# React cant read my argument inside my .map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have another data folder with nested objects inside arrays I want to access them with `.map` function. Its working perfectly fine with `divs` and `h3` but when it comes to this it says `y is not defined`

```
import Nav from './Nav'
import Cards from './Cards'
import data from './data'

export default function App(){

    return  ( data.map(y =>
        <Nav />,
        <Cards
        title = {y.title} // y is not recognized
        />
     ) )
}
```

Comment: Where is `y` comming from?

Comment: here you go i fixed the missing code

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint] 
src\App.js
  Line 10:18:  'y' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Are you sure your `Nav` component is meant to be _inside_ the `map`? Surely you're just meant to be generating the cards from that data...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add brackets:

```
return  ( data.map(y => (
    <>
<Nav />
    <Cards
    title = {y.title} 
    />
</>
) ) )
```

Comment: Another problem is that a component can't return an array, so this map should be wrapped with `<>{}</>`

Comment: @Konrad There is no problem with components returning arrays since React 16.